# Why wont my if else statement work

Tags: c++

The first two statements run with the given number input but the third statement doesn't run.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double X;

    cout << "Please pick a number from -10 to 10";

    cin >> X;

    if ((-3 <= X)&&( X <= 2))
        cout << "Y = " << ( X * X) + (2 * X) -3 << endl;

    else if ((2 < X)&&(X <= 10))
        cout << "Y = " << (5 * X) + 7 << endl;

    else if ((X > 10)&&(X < -3))
        cout << "Y = " << 0 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I choose `-10` or `11` the result I receive is just an end program not a "Y = 0 ".

Comment: because X can not be greater than 10 and less than -3 at the same time

Comment: @StevenHansen: No, `-10` does not satisfy the first one.  It becomes `((-3 <= -10) && (-10 <= 20))` which evaluates to `(false && true)` which is false.

Comment: It's not the cause of your bug, but [you should check whether `cin >> X` is successful](http://kayari.org/cxx/yunocheckio.html)

Comment: @StevenHansen, `(-3 <= X)&&( X <= 2)` is the idiomatic C or C++ way to express the mathematical inequality -3 ≤ X ≤ 2

Answer (score 6):

```
 if ((X > 10)&&(X < -3))
```

At a time `X` can't be `X` > 10 and `X` < -3 so it'll always return false.

So it can never go inside (3rd) `if` condition.

You might want to use `||` instead of `&&` so that if anyone is true it can go inside `if` condition:

```
if ((X > 10)||(X < -3))
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you suggesting

Comment: @StevenHansen: It's your misunderstanding, or more likely carelessness while reading the code, that has you perceiving the issue differently.

Comment: @StevenHansen OP specifically mentioned about choosing -10 or 11 and not hitting 3rd if condition.

Comment: @Steven: "Answer", not "reply".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I mentioned the answer also i.e. using ||

Comment: @JerryGoyal: That's not what I was referring to

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that one number cannot be greater then 10 and lower than -3 in one time.
For example 20 is greater then 10 but also greater then -3. You can't find this number.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the answers that have already been given.